# Client program in c for ipv6 connect is not working?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ipv6

/*client.c*/

```
 void main()
   {
    static int s = 0;
    char url_or_ip[130] = {0};
    int port = 0;
    ip_type_or_dns_enum ip_dns_type = -1;
    char *sptr = ext_sio_recv_buff;
    char *ip_str = NULL;
    char ip_buf[128] = {0};
    int isipv6 = 0;
    char buff[NWY_UART_RECV_SINGLE_MAX + 1] = {0};
    int on = 1;
    int opt = 1, ret = 0, send_len;
    uint64_t start;
    ip6_addr_t addr;
    struct sockaddr_in6 sa;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *to6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&sa;
    port = 8000;
    addr.addr[0] =  0x25035959;
    addr.addr[1] =  0x87493683; 
    addr.addr[2] =  0x2abf3de2; 
    addr.addr[3] =  0x1ab43f8e;



   /*socket creation*/

    s = socket_open(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    sa.sin6_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
    sa.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sa.sin6_port = htons(port);
   
   /*assigning the address for ipv6*/

    sa.sin6_addr.un.u32_addr[0] = htonl(addr.addr[0]);
    sa.sin6_addr.un.u32_addr[1] = htonl(addr.addr[1]);
    sa.sin6_addr.un.u32_addr[2] = htonl(addr.addr[2]);
    sa.sin6_addr.un.u32_addr[3] = htonl(addr.addr[3]);

socket_setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&on,sizeof(on));
socket_setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&opt, sizeof(opt));
 
  /*connect to the particular server*/  

  int ret = socket_connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
    if(ret >0)
    {
    socket_send(s, uart_rec_buffer, uart_length, 0);
    socket_shutdown(s, SHUT_RD);
    socket_close(s);
    s=0;
    }
  }
```

here i am trying to make ipv6 client connection to the ipv6 server, but in the connect system call it is failing . i tried to change the ip and checked still same issue. But the code fails in connect system call and returning -1 and showing invalid argument. Any suggestions. And the API's i am using are similar to the socket programming api's and the socket_open is similar to the socket creation and the socket_connect is similar to the connect system call and assinging the values to the ipv6 predefined structures, the socket is created successfully but socket_connect is failed, why? and it is showing invalid argument passed to the connect call..

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. Your current code contains many things irrelevant to the problem you're asking about. Also, what socket API are you using? What is `socket_connect`? Also please tell us how you notice the error, since the code you show doesn't include that.

Comment: Also please take some time to take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: You don't need to set SO_REUSEADDR on this client. `IPPROTO_TCP` doesn't look right. It should refer to IPv6 like the domain argument does.

Comment: @user207421--thanks for the reply, after removing the  SO_REUSEADDR still i am facing same using connect function is not working still it is showing invalid agrument and returning -1 ,and IPPROTO_TCP represents the protocol layer int socket_setsockopt(int s, int level, int optname, const void * optval, socklen_t optlen); Is there any worng in the ip assigning?